# blockquote works perfect on IE10 but not on IE9

Tags: html, css

I use blockquotes as you can see below:

```
<blockquote>Totally Loving this APP.<font size="3"> I recommend it for anyone in this planet wants to join the app world. </font>  </blockquote>
```

and my CSS is :

```
blockquote {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  border-left: 10px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1.5em 10px;
  padding: 0.5em 10px;
  quotes: "\201C""\201D";
}
blockquote:before {
  color: #ccc;
  content: open-quote;
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 0.1em;
  margin-right: 0.25em;
  vertical-align: -0.4em;
}
blockquote p {
  display: inline;
}
```

It works perfect on IE10, but it is not working on IE9. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Why on earth are you using `<font>` tags?

Comment: *What* doesn't work?  What do you see/not see in each browser?

Comment: ok, right, just ignore them...

Comment: `blockquote p` doesn't match anything here.  Should it?

Comment: on IE10 I get the text inside blackquote. On IE9 I get the text in blackquote but it is spread in 3 different lines and it should be in 1 line as on IE10

Comment: @user2491321, you are supposed to clarify the question by editing the question itself, not just in comments. A question should be self-contained, understandable when you just read it and no comments or answers.

Comment: The problem, what it might be in detail, is not reproducible with the code in the question.

Comment: Works for me in IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/da4t2ugo (Screenshot from VM: http://i.imgur.com/Ua3Ehby.png)

Comment: yes thank you, I see where was the problem!